# Transparent color not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, colors, html-select

The following code works perfectly in every other browser apart from Internet Explorer 9. 
Color transparent CSS does not work.

HTML:

```
<select class="selectElement" runat="server" id="dropdown_">
    <option value="N">N</option>
    <option value="G">G</option>
    <option value="O">O</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="R">R</option>
    <option value="U">U</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.selectElement {
    height: 50px;
    width: 80px;
    border: solid 1px #c8c8c8;
    color:transparent;   
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[id^=dropdown]').children().each(function () {
        colors = { "N": "lightgrey", "G": "green", "O": "orange", "A": "yellow", "R": "red", "U": "purple" }
        $(this).attr('style', 'background-color:' + colors[$(this).val()] + ';');
    });
    $('select[id^=dropdown]').change(function () {
        $(this).attr('style', $(this).find('option:selected').attr('style'));
    }).change();
    $('select[id^=dropdown]')
    .mousedown(function () { $(this).css('color', 'black') })
    .blur(function () { SetStyle(this) })
    .change(function () { SetStyle(this) })

    SetStyle('#dropdown'); // So that we style on load

    function SetStyle(obj) {
        var color = $(obj).find('option:selected').css('background-color');
        $(obj).css({
            'color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            'background-color': color
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What document mode are you rendering in in IE? What is the doctype you are using?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET web form

Comment: Jag, look at your html. At the beginning of the .aspx or whatever .. you'll see <!doctype html> or something similiar. also, you can push F12 (from windows) to pull up the developer tools in IE. You'll see Document Mode and Browser Mode there. What is it?

Comment: the DOCTYPE. Look at HI_Test_v1._Default. Where your html, head, and body tags are.. <!doctype html> <html> <head> ... </head> <body> ... </body> </html> ...

Comment: okay now i got it:
browser mode: IE9
doc mode: IE9 standards

Comment: i am sorry but i think i am not helping you - i might actually be confusing you more

Comment: Hi Jag, I think what he is asking is if you view the source of your rendered document, what is the very top line

Comment: Hi Pete, thanks. The first line only says:
<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Why do you want the text transparent rather than white?

Comment: it has to be transparent because the colors indicate something - having text in them while dorpdown is closed ruins the look. maybe if the text color could be changed to same as bg color, that could work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have a hard time trying to get the select menu styles to do what you want unless you use a plugin like jQuery Custom Select.

http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/

That being said, instead of doing this...

```
$(this).attr('style', 'background-color:' + colors[$(this).val()] + ';');
```

You could try this...

```
$(this).css({'background-color': colors[$(this).val()]});
```

Also, if IE is giving you any error messages that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid to directly change the `style` attribute in IE.

Instead, try this:

```
this.cssText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].cssText;
```

Comment: i can make the text color match the background color which gives me what i want but when the dropdown is open the user needs to be able to see what the colors mean